# JSON server to generate JSON ( in java language )

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jetty, json-api

I need to generate some JSON data (with java) to test them on clients. I read some documents but i am not sure how to start with jetty or tomcat or others.Besides, I am not sure i the "JSON api server" is what that I need or not. would you please let me know if you know any instruction to do that ?

thank you

Edit:

thank you I did that bu try Rest api server + jetty

Comment: You should have a look at Apache Wink: https://wink.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

With Apache wink your tomcat server becomes a rest api:

```
 @GET
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public JSONObject postJSON(JSONObject requestJSON) {
 String property = requestJSON.getString("property");
 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
 return jobj;
 }
 /* Book is a JAXB annotated class */
 @GET
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Book postJSONBook(Book requestBookEntity) {
 String title = requestBookEntity.getTitle();
 /* other code */
 Book response = new Book();
 return response;
 }
```

Your client will receive a json-string.

Comment: thank you , what is I want to have stream JSON api ? i mean i need to change the content of JSON api every 3 sec. is that possible ?

Comment: i tried this : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/  but i couldn't manage to run this !

Comment: this one is work : https://nikolaygrozev.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/rest-with-embedded-jetty-and-jersey-in-a-single-jar-step-by-step/    is there any way to change this to generate a new JSON data every 3 second ?

Comment: The server will answer every time your client is calling it, so yes it can.

Comment: thank you , but need to generate a new JSON every 3 sec . if i just call the server every 3 sec , it will give me the same JSNO .  i tried to use for-loop , but it didn't work. is there any way to generate new JSON every for example 3 sec ?

Comment: anyone knows how can generate new JSON for example every 3 sec with this project : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: should i use java scheduler ?

Comment: If the client is written in Java: use Timer: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jdk-timer-scheduler-example/   If your client is written javascript: use intervall http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: i post my error here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585110/java-generat-schediled-json

Comment: I have now answered the other queston. As I state there: you need to write the rest-api, and then write the client. The client is responsible for callint the server at a intervall

Comment: thank you @Skywalker , i will continue on that question