# JAVA- generate scheduled JSON

Tags: java, json, api, stream, jetty

I started with this :http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/ 
and created a JSON on localhost:8080...
I am not sure if  there is any way to generate new Json every 3 or 5 second. for example just add one digit to new JSON every 3 sec.

```js
@Path("/LNU.se")
public class EntryPoint { 
    @GET
    @Path("get")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test() {

        return "mahdi Test";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response postTest(Track track){

        String resault = " the track is saved mahdi: "+ track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(resault).build();
    }
}
```

and another class:

```js
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;


public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


           ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
            context.setContextPath("/");

            Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
            jettyServer.setHandler(context);

            ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
            jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

            jerseyServlet.setInitParameter( "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", EntryPoint.class.getCanonicalName());

                try {                   
                    jettyServer.start();
                    System.out.println(" open your browser on http://localhost:8080/LNU.se/get");
                      jettyServer.join();       

                } catch (Exception e) 
                {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {                 
                    jettyServer.destroy();
                }
    }
}
```

======================

UPDATE: -->

My server is:

```js
package rest;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
    import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

    public class RestServer {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
            context.setContextPath("/");
            Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
            jettyServer.setHandler(context);

            ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
                    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
            jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                    Calculator.class.getCanonicalName());
            try {
                jettyServer.start();
                System.out.println(" open the browser on http://localhost:8080/calculator/squareRoot?input=16");
                jettyServer.join();
            } finally {
                jettyServer.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this class:

```js
package rest;

    import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

    @Path("calculator")
    public class Calculator {

        Result ress = new Result("mahdi84");
        public static String resul1;  
        @GET
        @Path("mahdi")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Result  mahdi(){
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("validTime", "2016-02-24T11:00:00Z");          
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();          
            obj.put("mcc", resul1);
            obj.put("temprature", resul1+1);
            obj.put("Humidity", resul1+10);
            jsonArray.add(obj);
            json.put("\n  JSONdata --> ", jsonArray);
        ress.setInput(Double.parseDouble(resul1));
        ress.setOutput(Double.parseDouble(resul1));
        ress.setTestVar(resul1);
        ress.setTestVar2(json);
            return ress;
        }

        @POST
        @Path("/post")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response createDataInJSON(String data) { 
            resul1= data;          
            return Response.status(201).entity(result).build(); 
        }        
        static class Result{
            double input;
            double output;
            String action;
            Object testVar;
            JSONObject testVar2;
            public Result(){} 
            public JSONObject getTestVar2() {
                return testVar2;
            }
            public void setTestVar2(JSONObject testVar2) {
                this.testVar2 = testVar2;
            }

            public Object getTestVar() {
                return testVar;
            }

            public void setTestVar(Object testVar) {
                this.testVar = testVar;
            }

            public Result(String action) {
                this.action = action;
            }

            public String getAction() {
                return action;
            }

            public void setAction(String action) {
                this.action = action;
            }

            public double getInput() {
                return input;
            }

            public void setInput(double input) {
                this.input = input;
            }

            public double getOutput() {
                return output;
            }

            public void setOutput(double output) {
                this.output = output;
            }
        }
    }
```

and my client is:

```js
  import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
    public class JerseyClientPost extends TimerTask{
        public int cuntr = 0;       
      public static void main(String[] args) {        
        TimerTask mytask = new JerseyClientPost();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(mytask, 1000, 1000);

        }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/calculator/post");           
            String input = Integer.toString(cuntr++);
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
            if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ response.getStatus());
            }
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

          } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }     
      }  
    }
```

the client will post to the server  every 1 sec and the server will generate new JSON on "http://localhost:8080/calculator/mahdi"
 when i try to read from "http://localhost:8080/calculator/mahdi" by apache http1.1 in another program :
package HttpClient;

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class MyHttpClient  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{                
        HttpGet requset = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/calculator/mahdi");    
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(requset);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8"));        
            System.out.println("Reading began ... ");

            while (true) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }               
            }   
    }
}
```

edit:

thank you I did that by using TImeTask class

it only print the first JSON! but when I refresh the weblink, it is updating on browser.
would you please correct me if I am wrong? I want to see the stream of JSON on MyHttpClient, but it only shows the first JSON!

Comment: To so something every N seconds you need a Timer or ScheduledExecutorService, and if you want to increment a number before generating the JSON message you can use `++`

Comment: can you please give me an example ? since i tried to put get ... post inside the run(){..} but getting error . your example can help me so much

Comment: There is 28K example of how to use ScheduledExecutorService. If you are getting an error, I suggest you read it, google it or post it here so we can tell you want it means. (Most likely we will google it for you)

Comment: i google that , and couldn't fond any help and that is the reason that i ask here.

Comment: What did you google? What was the error?

Comment: is there any solution for my problem ? i getting just first JSON and the others is null !

Comment: finally  I fixed that, thank you @skywalker. I used client extend to TimeTask and tried to poll from http every 3 sec and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things. The server should only be a server, and not extend TimerTask. The client should call the server at a specific intervall

Do the follwing:

1. Test your server in a web-browser. Make sure that it will respond.
2. Write a client either in Java or javascript If you are using Java
   the client should have a http-client.
3. The client should hava a timertask calling the the server at a specific intervall

Comment: thank you @Skywalker, but if a client call the sever for example every 3 sec, the same data will be put on the locallost:8080..  , I am trying to generate JSON data to check the streaming . maybe I can't convey what I mean.

Comment: The klient could be anywhere. Say that the server monitors the water level. You would like to check that the water lever every thrid second on the client. Then the client must send a request to the server every third second. The client could be on a phone or on a computer in another city. However the server could write a copy of each request to a log locally, to monitor the requests. Then both the client and the server would have a copy of the data.